# Нужно поставить таймер на бота Вконтакте. Бот написан на Python

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, таймер

Мне нужно добавить таймер боту, так чтобы команду "ТЗ", можно было бы выполнять 1 раз в 30 минут.

Пример:

я) Тз

бот) вот ваше ТЗ

я) Тз

бот) Подождите 30 минут, перед получением нового задания

Отрывок кода:

```
            vk.messages.send(
                    user_id=event.user_id,
                    random_id=event.random_id,
                    message='Привет, я Креативный Дизайнер!\n\nЯ сгенерирую для тебя рандомное техническое задание. С помощью меня ты сможешь набраться опыта, пополнить своё портфолио новыми работами и развить креативность. Готов начать?\n\nНапиши мне команду «ТЗ»'
                    )
        #Техническое задание
        elif event.text.lower() in commands_list[0]:
            vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event.user_id,
                random_id=event.random_id,
                message='Техническое задание:\n\nНужно сделать:\n– '+Order_list [random.randint(0, 6)]+'\n\nТематика:\n–'+Thematics [random.randint(0, 36)]+'\n\nОсновные цвета:\n–'+colors_list [random.randint(0, 31)]+', '+colors_list [random.randint(0, 31)]
            #ТУТ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ТАЙМЕР
                )
            #Неправильная команда
        else:
            vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event.user_id,
                random_id=event.random_id,
                message='Я вас не понимаю.\nНапишите «ТЗ»'
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно отправить ТЗ через 30 минут - Вы можете воспользоваться [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) или [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) для создания отложенных задач.
Если же отправлять не требуется - Вы можете проверить когда Вы отправляли последний раз ТЗ и в случае, если прошло менее 30 минут - сообщить пользователю об этом

Comment: можете подробнее рассказать про проверку?

Comment: как это можно реализовать, только не ругайтесь я новичок)

Comment: Вам нужно получить время отправки предыдущего ТЗ данному пользователю и проверить, прошло ли полчаса с момента его отправки

```python
. . .
elif event.text.lower() in commands_list[0]:
    if time_sending_prev_TS + timedelta(minutes=30) >= datetime.now():
        # Отправить сообщение о том, что можно получать ТЗ только раз в 30 минут
    else:
        # отправить ТЗ
else:
. . .

```

Comment: А чему должно ровняться time_sending_prev_TS

Comment: это как раз и будет время отправки предыдущего ТЗ

Comment: ошибка: NameError: name 'time_sending_prev_TS' is not defined

Comment: всё верно, так как вы не объявили эту переменную. вам нужно объявить её и присвоить ей время отправки последнего ТЗ. Каким именно образом вы его определите - вопрос другой

Comment: А вы знаете как это можно сделать?

Comment: судя по всему, вам будет нужно хранить у себя когда и какому пользователю вы отправили тз. там находить для данного пользователя время отправки последнего тз

Comment: Можно я создам  чат и вы там подробнее расскажите?)

Comment: хорошо, давайте

Comment: К сожалению у меня не хватает репутации, не могли бы вы, скинуть пример кода, как можно присвоить это значение